# File icons with clocks

Tags: files, icons

How do I fix my icons?

[image: [icons]

I tried installing adwaita full icons theme with the below command.

```
sudo apt install adwaita-icon-theme-full
```

But it didn't fix it.

When I change to adwaita they just look like this.

[image: [look like this]